# range of complex function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ where z on the unit circle 1 centered at the z=1

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So, I know that $z=\{1+e^{ix}|x \in{(-\pi,\pi]}\}$. I also know the image is equal to $\{\frac12+ai|a\in{\mathbb{R}}\}$. But I'm stuck in trying to solve $1\over 1+e^{ix}$.

Comment: I think you have a typo somewhere - $z = 0$ is on the unit circle centered at $1$, but $\frac{1}{0 + 1} = 1$ is not of the form $\frac{1}{2} + ai$. Do you mean $f(z) = 1/z$?

Comment: You might have meant $\frac{1}{z}$, as circles through the origin gets mapped to lines not through the origin.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a geometrical approach:
Consider the transformation: $z\mapsto z+1$.
This will shift the unit circle centred at $1$ to a unit circle centred at $2$.

Then apply the transformation: $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$
The reciprocal mapping maps circles not through the origin to circles not through the origin. The closest point to the origin will be the furthest point from the origin under the mapping and the furthest point from the origin will map to be the closest point to the origin.
The diameter can be determined by the distance between these two new points, and the centre can also be determined by taking the midpoint.
A circle is uniquely identified by its diameter and centre.

Comment: Nice answer, only slightly dissimilar to what I would have said. I would have suggested to OP, though, that seeing the general element of the domain as having form $1+\exp(it)$ for real $t$ was not the best route to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply $f (z)$ by $\frac{(1+e^{-i x})}{(1+e^{-i x})}
 $, expand and use the trigonometric representation of $e^{\pm i x}$. Use the identity $1+\cos x = 2 \, \cos^2 \frac{x}{2}$ and you get $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2} tg \frac{x}{2}$. The image of $tg \frac{x}{2}$ is the whole $\mathbf{R}$.